# Each line in write function gets an increasing number

Tags: python

Trying to make a function to print out a list of objects, where each object has got a number infront of it. For example:
1 "Object 1"
2 "Object 2"
3 "Object 3" 
And so on. I tried making a function like this:

```
n=0
for x in ObjectList: 
    n+=1 
    file=open(fileName, "w")
    file.write("\n".join(n, str(x) for x in Object))
```

But I am getting errors any way I try this, how could I go about doing this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument.. which happens any way I parenthesize it

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of  problems with your code.

- `for x in Object` : What is `Object` here?
- You are opening the same file multiple times in the loop.
- You are not closing the file.

---

What you'd need is something like below:

```
with open(fileName, 'w') as f:
    for index, obj in enumerate(ObjectList):
        print>>f, index, obj
```

Comment: use `enumerate(ObjectList, 1)` to start counting at 1.

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you want to do?

```
ObjectList = ["foo","bar","baz"]
file=open(fileName, "w")
for i in range(len(ObjectList)):
    file.write("%d %s\n" % (i,ObjectList [i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to open the file and write to it on every iteration of your loop.  Instead, compile a string with everything you want and write that single string at the end.  Something like this:

```
n=0
lines = []
for x in ObjectList: 
    n+=1 
    lines.append(str(n)+str(x)) #you may want more whitespace here
lines = "\n".join(lines)
with open(fileName, "w") as f:
    f.write(lines)
```

you can also make it much more concise with `enumerate` and a list comprehension:

```
lines = [(str(n)+str(x) for n,x in enumerate(ObjectList, 1)]
lines = "\n".join(lines)
with open(fileName, "w") as f:
    f.write(lines)
```

Always use the `with open...` syntax to open a file (unless you are doing something different on purpose).  You can do what you want with it in the subsequent code block, and then it will be automatically closed for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
objectList = ['object1', 1, 1.2, 'object4']

stringOfObjects = '\n'.join(["%i: %s"%(i,x) for i,x in enumerate(objectList, 1)])
print stringOfObjects
```

This what you wanted?

> 1: object1
>   2: 1
>   3: 1.2
>   4: object4